# Identifying if an image is a photograph of a monitor or electronic device using Python

Tags: python, image-processing

So as part of a project I am required to download images and check if they are photographs of a monitor or electronic devices. I know that whenever you take a photo of a monitor displaying something there are curved lines all over the photo, which is a fairly distinguishing feature of such photos. I was wondering if there was any way to use that.
Any other approaches are also welcome. The code to verify it does not have to be in python but it would make my life a lot easier.
[image: second type of image]
[image: undistorted image for comparison]
[image: example of image with lines]

Comment: Can you post an image illustrating the curved lines?  Thanks.

Comment: @MarkLavin this is what it looks like. Most images are like this.

Comment: Yes, I see it, sort of an interference pattern.   It's not clear how to separate the "figure" (the curved color bands) from the "ground" (everything else).   It's going to be tough to do unless there are constraints on what is depicted.   If it's always black print on a white background (plus the interference pattern) then I can image some kind of low-pass filtering that might suppress the print so you could look for curving color edges.

Comment: @MarkLavin what about the second type of photo, I've added it to the question.

Comment: That's a little different than the first image, since the "interference fringes" have a more consistent spacing.   Nevertheless, it still seems tough to figure out a way to do it.   Perhaps it's worth looking at a Convolutional Neural Network and train it on image:label pairs.   I just googled, and found https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050920311613, which is about texture detection.

Comment: please provide an undistorted image for comparison

Comment: @anon01 the second image is an example of an undistorted image.